# Please check grammar of this sentence

Tags: grammar

I need to write an email to office team members siting reasons for not meeting the production target.

Had below constraints were not there, we would have exceeded the target.

Comment: Please note, as kind as Billy Kerr has been to respond to your question, that this site does not offer proofreading, improvements to suggested prose or answers to homework.  It is intended to deal with questions about grammar, expression, or usage, one at a time.

Comment: citing not siting

Comment: @RonaldSole, I didn't intend to offer proof reading here, merely an explanation of what's wrong with the example, I think grammar questions are fine. Maybe the wording of the question could be better - perhaps "Is there a grammatical problem with the construction of this sentence?", but were dealing with learners here who may have some difficulty expressing themselves.

Comment: @BillyKerr Please note that it was your kindness that I highlighted.

Comment: @RonaldSole - I did, thanks.

Comment: @BillyKerr - Yes, but posters are discouraged from just asking "Is this sentence correct?"

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct, there are several problems.

You've used the wrong form of the verb **to be**.  The auxiliary verb **had** goes with **been** (the past participle), not **were** (the simple past). This is how you form the past perfect tense. Also the word order is messed up.

The construction needs to be: **Had X not been there . . .**

Also "below constraints" sounds very strange, non-native. Use this instead: "the constraints shown (or listed) below".  You could also say "the constraints below".  You can't omit "the" - it's required.

Comment: "the below constraints" is perfectly okay to this native Brit's ears. "Had the below constraints not been there..." actually sounds better than "Had the constraints below not been there" -- the latter makes you want to read it that the constraints were actually "below the situation" rather than "listed below this sentence", and then when you get to the end of the sentence you have to un-derail yourself to get the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @PrimeMover I'm also British - it's just too weird IMHO, but likely a matter of opinion. I'd avoid it. "the constraints shown below" is less ambiguous, or perhaps even "the constraints listed below".

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are off-topic for the site, like proofreading.